# k8s pod completing even though I have an infinite loop in pod.yaml

Tags: kubernetes

I have below pod.yaml file and I am expecting the pod to keep running but it completes.
Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: base
    image: "alpine:latest"
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "while true; do echo app1:$(date -u) >> /data/test.log; sleep 5; done"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: persistent-storage
      mountPath: /data
  volumes:
  - name: persistent-storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: emy-claim
```

Comment: what do you mean by completes? Pods dont complete, they either run or not more or less. If they are not running, kubernetes will restart them. Also note that you have a bug in your args. You need to escape the $() with an extra dollar sign.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes are you using? for me if I skip the volume, the pod stays in a `Running` state for me. I tested on `v1.26.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the `pod.yaml` file with the below information to keep the pod running using the `while` condition and to update the `log entries` continuosly in the `test` file under `data` directory for every `5 seconds`.

```
args: ["-c", "while true; do echo echo $(date -u) 'app1' >>  /data/test.log; sleep 5; done"]
```

Please see the [documentation](https://learning-ocean.com/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-side-car-container) for more details.